# Links between patriotism and racism

Tags: ethics

Is there any published research which attempts to establish a possible link between *extreme patriotism* and *institutionalized racism*? What do they conclude?

Comment: You're going to have to expand on this a bit. I'm not sure many people will just *leap* to the conclusion you've made without some explanation...

Comment: Great questions ask about one specific thing; it would be good if you could focus in a bit more closely on the problem you're facing in your study of philosophy. Is there any way I might encourage you to develop this a little bit more? Can you perhaps tell us a bit about your context and motivations, and maybe a little bit more about where you might be coming from here? What might you be reading that made this an important or urgent theoretical concern? What might you have found out so far?

Comment: It seems ppl on this forum speak some sort of code language you need to be more exact as Almost every question I ask here gets shut what does one specific thing mean Patriotism is one specific thing to me tell me where to go I don't understand your issue with all my questions it is simply intolerable the culture of does not suit me lets close it how about someone editing and helping instead of closing to encourage like an open project is supposed to be like in the comments saying do you mean sorry about the rant but I think some constructive criticism here is sorely lacking

Comment: @YUASK: Here's some constructive criticism, then.  This site is a Q&A site for asking questions *about* philosophy, not for asking philosophical questions.  So, if you are doing some research on patriotism and racism in a particular philosophical tradition, and have a question about what you are reading, that question would be welcomed and upvoted.  A question asking us to philosophize, on the other hand, such as a question asking our collective opinions about the relationship between patriotism and racism, is likely to be downvoted or closed.

Comment: The text on the "close" message is quite clear about this: **We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion**

Comment: Michael, thank you for clearing that up(philosophize versus about philosophy)  but how about How about this editing the question so that it is not A question asking members to philosophize

Comment: @YUASK: You are free to edit your questions at any time, even closed ones. If you address the problems of a closed question, it will be reopened.

Comment: I have attempted that to no avail and ended up deleting the questions its a quite high standard for questions here

Comment: @YUASK: "High" is a relative term, but yes we do have standards. Unfortunately, outside of a little room for judgment calls here and there, neither the community members nor the moderators set the standard. It is set by the owners of the StackExchange network. If you think the standards ought to be relaxed, consider making a meta post about it to grab the attention of someone in a position to change it. I'm sure they will be able to provide you reasons why the system is set up the way it is. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there are not any studies, at least that I know of, that directly link extreme patriotism and *institutionalized* racism there are multiple studies which links conservatism to patriotism/loyalty towards the in-group and a higher dislike and distrust of out-groups. We could then deduct, but not with any certainty, that racism stems from a dislike and distrust of out-groups.

I would be very cautious though when talking about this because a dislike or distrust of an out-group A) Does not directly relate to racism B) Has shown to have genetic reasons as to why an in-group would dislike or distrust an out-group.

With that said the link below goes to a study that shows how people who are conservative are more loyal and in-group based. http://web.ebscohost.com/ehost/detail?sid=89be3139-cbd6-4c9d-8137-faa4696592e6%40sessionmgr14&vid=1&hid=15&bdata=JnNpdGU9ZWhvc3QtbGl2ZSZzY29wZT1zaXRl#db=pdh&AN=psp-96-5-1029

This link goes to a study that explains why certain in-groups would have a distrust of out-groups. The intention of this study is to show how living conditions may have genetically effected humans into having a distrust or dislike of an out-group but within the study it states how conservatives are more likely to have these feelings. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1469-185X.2008.00062.x/full

The logic behind this would be that from an evolutionary standpoint it was beneficial at times to be distrusting of out-groups. Because genes do not simply disappear but tend to linger this distrust still remains while the reasons for the distrust may still not be there. This answer may be more biological based then you hoped but it is a possible answer but should definitely not be interpreted as a fact or truth, it is solely a possible explanation.